# Expose External Object via enterprise wsdl

Tags: enterprise-wsdl

I know we can access data of Standard/Custom objects using Enterprise WSDL. But is there any way to expose `External object` through Enterprise WSDL?

Any help/guide line?

Comment: Have you tried to generate wsdl from org that contains those objects?

Comment: Yes but did not find external object information in that wsdl.

Comment: Then looks like parent api is the only way to access those.